# Why is the installer downloading the whole game again when I have already downloaded during my pre-order?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'd pre-ordered Diablo III quite some time back and downloaded and ran the installer which then proceeded to download the full game.

However, today when I try to install Diablo III, it's redownloading the entire 8gb set of files. I've also downloaded the [new installer](http://eu.battle.net/support/en/blog/4417006), yet it proceeds to download the entire game.

What can I do to make the installer recognize that I've already downloaded the game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blizzard had posted [this post](http://eu.battle.net/support/en/blog/4417006) which mentions that the initial installers had a bug. The post mentions:

> - Obtain the new Diablo III digital downloader using the links below
>
>   - [EU English Installer - Windows](http://eu.media.battle.net.edgesuite.net/downloads/d3-installers/589acdb4-c660-318a-b993-01528fad7da6/Diablo-III-8370-enGB-Installer-downloader.exe)
>   - [EU English Installer - Mac](http://eu.media.battle.net.edgesuite.net/downloads/d3-installers/589acdb4-c660-318a-b993-01528fad7da6/Diablo-III-8370-enGB-Installer-downloader.zip)
>   - [German Installer - Windows](http://eu.media.battle.net.edgesuite.net/downloads/d3-installers/589acdb4-c660-318a-b993-01528fad7da6/Diablo-III-8370-enGB-Installer-downloader.zip)
>   - [German Installer - Mac](http://eu.media.battle.net.edgesuite.net/downloads/d3-installers/589acdb4-c660-318a-b993-01528fad7da6/Diablo-III-8370-deDE-Installer-downloader.zip)
> - Point the download save at the same directory as before. The folder in question is your main game data folder. If you have the game
>     downloaded to `D:\Games\Diablo-III-8370-enGB-Installer`, please point
>     the download to `D:\Games\`.
>
>   Do not use the automatically generated folder containing the
>     installation files (i.e. do not use the directory
>     D:\Games\Diablo-III-8370-enGB-Installer as this is the one created by
>     the downloader).
>     **If you chose the correct directory only 50MB will need to be downloaded to fix your install, otherwise you'll re-download the
>     entire ~7.6GB**

Also, it's absolutely imperative that you **download the same language & region client** that you used to download the game after pre-ordering.

In my case, I had downloaded the En-GB version of installer & game after pre-ordering. However, today while downloading the new installer, Blizzard offered me the US version of the installer & because of this mismatch, it was downloading the whole game again.

After grabbing the En-GB(aka EU) install client, it was able to detect my previous download.